# how can I require macOS user password before mounting a USB device to the mac?

Tags: macos, usb, password, mount

How can I require macOS user password before mounting a USB device to the mac? I don't mind that all USB devices need the same password to mount.

I had a thought that this would improve security, that it would be harder to transfer files quickly from a machine even if they had access to the machine.

PS: I can already achieve encrypted disks. I'm more worried about strangers/people mounting their own, unencrypted disk onto my machine.

Not sure where to start with trying this.

[image: Example prompt from macOS to proceed with system preferences]

Comment: Can you please add details about what you want to accomplish to the question *text*? Things get easily lost or overlooked in the title.

Comment: You want it the other way round, rather than that the volume is password-protected, the act of the mount is password protected?  I think you'd be better off just disabling USB storage.

Comment: I've updated the text, thanks! `the act of the mount is password protected?` Yes! I still want to be able to mount devices after putting my password in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty much what you want if you have a MacBook (not a desktop Mac) with Apple Silicon. In the Privacy & Security settings, select one of the options for "Allow accessories to connect" other than "Always." Make sure the screen is locked whenever you're away from the machine.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102282

I don't know of a comparable solution for desktop models.

Comment: This is unfortunately really tedious, since even my external keyboard won't work until I accept it. It doesn't work with my desk setup. However, setting it to ask for new devices is already good enough. I'm worried about new devices being plugged in.